# transfer some checkboxes from an ActionListener to another ActionListener

Tags: java, swing

I would like to check what checkboxes are selected after I click button `b`,
but my checkboxes are declared after I clicked button `b1`

I mean, should I declare the `checkbox[]` globally? And how can I do that?

```java
b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
       JCheckBox checkbox[] = new JCheckBox[3];
       checkbox[0] = new JCheckBox("Red");
       checkbox[1] = new JCheckBox("Blue");
       checkbox[2] = new JCheckBox("Green");
    }
});

b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(checkbox[0].isSelected())
          // do something
       if(checkbox[1].isSelected())
          // do something
       if(checkbox[2].isSelected())
          // do something
    }
});
```

> Error: checkbox cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: My bad, sorry, I already edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The checkboxes array should be visible to both listeners. One option is as an instance variable.

For example (won’t actually compile, just a snippet):

```
   private JCheckBox[] checkboxes;

   void register() {
     s1.addListener(e -> {
        checkboxes = new JCheckBox[3];
        // do the rest
     };

     s2.addListener(e -> {
         if(checkboxes[0].isChecked()) {
         } 
         // ....
      };
    }
```

However, this is a bad design, as the *checkboxes* member is not fully initialized for use, which might lead to *NullPointerException*. 
Instead you would probably be better of initializing the array in the constructor or something.

Consider:

```
   private JCheckBox[] checkboxes;

    SomeClass() {
      checkboxes = new JCheckBox[3];
       // do the rest
     }

     void register() {
       s2.addListener(e -> {
         if(checkboxes[0].isChecked()) {
         } 
         // ....
      };
    }
```

Comment: That's works, I just needed to declare `private JCheckBox[] checkbox`  outside. Thank you

Comment: I would still like to emphasize that although it works, you should make sure the design is actually clean. Kind of a generic say, but an important one.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to declare your `JCheckBox[] checkbox = new JCheckBox[3];` outside of the action listener method.

Here is an example

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Scratch {
    private static JCheckBox[] checkbox = null;
    private static int checkBoxNo = 10;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JButton creteB = new JButton("Create");
        final JButton checkB = new JButton("Check");
        final JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner();
        final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

        creteB.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
            if (checkbox != null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Already created");
                return;
            }
            final int number = (int) spinner.getValue();

            if (number < checkBoxNo) {
                checkBoxNo = number;
            }

            checkbox = new JCheckBox[checkBoxNo];

            for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxNo; ++i) {
                checkbox[i] = new JCheckBox("" + i);
                jFrame.add(checkbox[i]);
            }

            jFrame.pack();
        });

        checkB.addActionListener(e -> {
            if (checkbox == null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "First press on creat button");
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxNo; ++i) {
                if (checkbox[i].isSelected()) {
                    checkbox[i].setForeground(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        });

        jFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.add(creteB);
        jFrame.add(checkB);
        jFrame.add(spinner);
        jFrame.pack();
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

In the above example I also used:

- [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.AccessibleJOptionPane.html) used to display information to the user in a popup message box (or dialog box)
- [JSpinner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?javax/swing/JSpinner.html) used to select the number of check boxes
- [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) used to define the action listener functionality (available only from java 8).

```
new JButton().addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

is equivalent to

```
new JButton().addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: most complete answer yet. I especially appreciate the message dialogs :) Maybe you could explain OP the lambda shortcut you used? These things are not self-explanatory.

Comment: But I have a `JTextField` named `tf1`. And I don't now the exactly length of `checkbox`. I need to take the text from `tf1` with `tf1.getText()` and compare with something. And if is `true` to add some checkboxes. And after that in  `b` to verify what checkboxes was checked, and do something. `b` is a button that literally end my program.

Comment: @MihaiBuzatu Check the updated code. You can put the list as a class filed

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare your Swing components (the `JCheckBoxes`) inside the `actionPerformed` method of your `ActionListener`. I suppose your buttons are part of some Panel or Frame?

```
public MyFrame extends JFrame{

   ...
   // somewhere in your container you have those buttons declared
   JButton b1 = new JButton("b1");
   JButton b = new JButton("b"); 
   // add your checkbox declarations here
   JCheckBox checkbox[] = new JCheckBox[3];
   checkbox[0] = new JCheckBox("Red");
   checkbox[1] = new JCheckBox("Blue");
   checkbox[2] = new JCheckBox("Green");

   // if you don't want them visible just yet, then declare them invisible:
   checkbox[0].setVisible(false);
   ..

   // then you declare your listeners:
   b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        checkboxes[0].setVisible(true);  // or whatever action you want 
    }
   });

   b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(checkbox[0].isSelected())
        // do something
        if(checkbox[1].isSelected())
        // do something
        if(checkbox[2].isSelected())
        // do something
     }
   });
  ...

}
```

**EDIT**

Let's put aside the idea of a "dynamic UI" for now.

You have GUI components (Buttons, InputFields, CheckBoxes...) and you have different "actions" you want to perform on those components. Even when the user actions and interactions appear complicated, you can still keep your code simple.

When **all** your GUI components are declared in the same frame, you can access them in the methods of your frame without problems.

For example, you can write a method (inside your Frame class) that handles the action for the `b` button:

```
private void onBClicked(){                             // method inside your frame
   if(this.checkbox[0].isSelected()){                  // here you can access all components from the frame
       String input = this.myTextInputField.getText(); // and handle the user's input
       if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("awesome")){
           checkbox[1].setSelected(true);
       }else{
           this.myTextInputField.setText("Try again");
       } 
       this.repaint();     // this is just a fallback to ensure that Java updates the GUI for your (the "this" is the frame)
   }
}
```

Like this you can write all your actions as simple methods inside the frame. In order to execute the method you declare the listener:

```
...
JButton b = new JButton("b");
b.addActionListener(this::onBClicked);  // right after declaring the button, you add the listener
```

the notation

```
 addActionListener(this::onBClicked);
```

is a shortcut for

```
addActionListener(e -> {
   this.onBClicked();
});
```

which is a shortcut for

```
addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
       MyFrame.this.onBClicked();
    }
});
```

Because `ActionListener` has only one method that you have to implement, so you can pass the name of the method you want to call directly as an argument.

And this you do for all your buttons. 
Don't worry about "global"/"local" problems right away. As long your frame exists, your Buttons will exist, and as long your buttons exist, their ActionListeners will exists, so as long your ActionListeners exist you want to be able to execute and manipulate the content of the frame.

Comment: But if I have a `JTextField` named `tf1`. And I want if I pressed  `b1`, to check if what I write in JTextField it's equal with something else, then to add some checkboxes. And after that if I check the checkboxes to do something. I can post my full code if you want. But I can't declare the checkboxes outside the  `void actionPerformed ` function

Comment: The buttons  and the Textfield are part of a Frame